# Problema de recepción de 0 byte a int por medio de I2C

Tags: c++, c, arduino

buenas noches tengo un problema, alguien que me pueda ayudar con un problema en el monitor serial y en el hardware. La idea es que por medio de I2C, tenga conectado un Master y un Slave. El Maestro le envía señales como altos y bajos al esclavo y eso se evalúa pero no me reconoce cuando trato de enviar un HIGH.
He intentado utilizando la función Wire.onReceive y mejoró el asunto. Sin embargo sigue sin reconocer los ALTOS.

He aquí el código del Maestro:

```
//      MASTER      //

#include <Wire.h>


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin(); // Master //

  Serial.println("Listo Slave");
}

void loop() {
  int H = 1; // 72
  int L = 0; // 76

  Wire.beginTransmission(5);
  Wire.write(H);
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
  delay(500); 

  Wire.beginTransmission(5); 
  Wire.write(L);
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
  delay(500); 
  
}
```

He aquí el código del Esclavo:

```
//      SLAVE      // 

#include <Wire.h> 
int led = 8; 

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(5); // SLAVE //
  Wire.onReceive(read_master); 
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Listo Maestro"); 

  pinMode(led, OUTPUT); 
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW); 

  

}

void loop() { 
  delay(1000);

}

void read_master(int howMany) {

  while(1 < Wire.available()) {


    int master_signal_high = Wire.read(); 

    if(master_signal_high==1){
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    Serial.println( master_signal_high ); 
    Serial.println(" Led turned on "); 

    delay(500);
    }
  }

  int master_signal_low = Wire.read(); 
  Serial.println(master_signal_low);
  
  //if ( master_signal_low == 0 ) 
  //{   
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    Serial.println(" Led turned off ");
  //}

  delay(500);
  
}
```

Por favor, estaría muy agradecido con quien me de una ayuda :(

Answer (score 2):

Algunas observaciones:

**Direcciones reservadas**

I2C tiene reservada la dirección 0x05, junto con otras.

Esta es la tabla de direcciones en binario:

```
Dirección    Uso
-----------------------------
 0000 0000   General Call
 0000 0001   Start Byte
 0000 001X   CBUS Addresses
 0000 010X   Reserved for Different Bus Formats
 0000 011X   Reserved for future purposes
 0000 1XXX   High-Speed Master Code
 1111 0XXX   10-bit Slave Addressing
 1111 1XXX   Reserved for future purposes
```

Usare para 0x2c como dirección por ninguna razón en especial.

**Operación en bytes**

`Wire.write` puede enviar un byte, un string, o un arreglo de bytes. En este último caso, debes indicar el largo del arreglo.

`Wire.read` retorna un sólo byte.

Para evitar equivocaciones, cambie todos los `int` por `byte`, pues si le pasas un `int` sólo enviara un byte de los dos.

**Master**

No necesitas hacer un `endTransmission` tras cada byte.

Agregue código para parpadear el LED integrado con cada byte enviado.

```
#include <Wire.h>

byte slave_address = 0x2c;

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin(); // Master //

  Serial.println("Listo Slave");
}

void loop() {
  byte H = 1; // 72
  byte L = 0; // 76

  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  Wire.beginTransmission(slave_address);
  Wire.write(H);

  delay(500);
   
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  Wire.write(L);
  Wire.endTransmission(0); 

  delay(500);
}
```

**Slave**

El callback `read_master` ejecuta dentro de una interrupción. El código debe ser tan corto como sea posible. No es recomendable hacer `Serial.print` adentro, aunque puede que funcione. Si necesitas imprimir algo, deja el dato en una variable global e imprimelo dentro de `loop`.

Ahora el `callback` incrementa un contador global, que luego se despliega en el Monitor Serial, para efectos de depuración.

El `callback` recibe la cuenta de bytes en el buffer de entrada; no es necesario preguntar cuantos hay.

```
#include <Wire.h>
int count = 0;
byte my_address = 0x2c;

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(my_address); // SLAVE //
  Wire.onReceive(read_master);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Listo Maestro");

  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print(count);
  Serial.print(" ");
  delay(500);
}

void read_master(int howMany) {

  count++;
  while (howMany--) {
    byte master_signal = Wire.read();
    if (master_signal) {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    } else {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Nota: Probé con un par de Arduino Uno. Conecte A4-A4, A5-A5 y GND-GND. No use pullups.

Al principio use un par de Wemos R1 mini que tenía más a mano, pero el código nunca funcionó. Puse un analizador lógico y lo único que detecte fue un pulso a intervalos, no una comunicación I2C. Lo pase al Uno y anduvo de inmediato. ¿Por qué? ni idea.